# How can I declare a datatype for an array of objects in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have data that looks like this:

```
var abc = [{ "id": 1, "name": "x" }, { "id": 2, "name": "x" }]
```

Can someone tell me how I can declare a datatype for this in Typescript ? Can I go so far as to declare that the objects contain and "id" and "name" field?

Comment: You can just declare an interface for things that have an int `id` and a `name` string. One of the things TypeScript got right is that it has structural typing. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use interface defined explicitly or we can just use inline type definition

```
// inline type 
var abc: {id:number;name:string}[] =
  [{ "id": 1, "name": "x" }, { "id": 2, "name": "x" }]

// wrong
// var abc: {id:number;name:string}[] = [{ x : 1}]


// explicit interface  
interface IData{
    id:number;
    name:string;
}

var def: IData[] =
   [{ "id": 1, "name": "x" }, { "id": 2, "name": "x" }]

// wrong 
// var def: IData[] = [{x : 1 }]
```

check both [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20abc%3A%20%7Bid%3Anumber%3Bname%3Astring%7D%5B%5D%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%5B%7B%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%20%22name%22%3A%20%22x%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%20%22name%22%3A%20%22x%22%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20wrong%0D%0A%2F%2F%20var%20abc%3A%20%7Bid%3Anumber%3Bname%3Astring%7D%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20x%20%3A%201%7D%5D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0Ainterface%20IData%7B%0D%0A%09id%3Anumber%3B%0D%0A%09name%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20def%3A%20IData%5B%5D%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%5B%7B%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%20%22name%22%3A%20%22x%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%20%22name%22%3A%20%22x%22%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20wrong%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20var%20def%3A%20IData%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%7Bx%20%3A%201%20%7D%5D)